# MySQL - SUBSTRING_INDEX between multiple points

Tags: mysql

I know this is far from the optimal way of doing things, but it is something that needs to be done infrequently, so I don't want to look at modifying the database / applications.

I have a database field `DataField` (BLOB) which contains a string of data in the format:

> "1,,0,13424556,item,something"

however that field may contain multiple instances (Sometimes 4 or 5 instances)e.g.

> "1,,0,13424556,item,something\r\n"1,,1,12345888,itemOther,somethingElse"

I need to find a way (in MySQL) to split this up to display each item individually (in it's own column). But can't find a way of doing this. (In fact if at all possible I need just the number string from each one (e.g.

```
13424556
```

))

I have the below query which is a start:

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING_INDEX(`DataField`,'\r\n',1),
SUBSTR(`DataField`, LOCATE('\r\n',`DataField`)+2, (CHAR_LENGTH(`DataField`) -     LOCATE('\r\n',REVERSE(`DataField`) )- LOCATE('\r\n',`DataField`))) AS e2
FROM table3;
```

This works if there are only two items, but not if there are 3 or more.

If anyone can expand on this I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might get you going in the right direction:

```
select 
substring_index(
  substring_index(case when `DataField` like "%\r\n" then `DataField` else concat(`DataField`,"\r\n") end,
  "\r\n",2),
"\r\n",-1)
from table3;
```

This will return you the second item. Replace the `2` with `3` to get the third, `4` to get the fourth etc etc.

You might have to tweak it a little....

Comment: Cheers, that worked quite nicely for what I need. I'll have to see if I can get it down to just the number that I want now. . .